# Parse expression with JavaScript using peggy js

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, peg

I have written a pseudo code to determine whether the string contains `*` or not and return the position(start, end, and wrapped) if it contains please check the code sandbox.

The problem is the code works correctly for the string which contains `*` at the beginning i.e. `*string`, for other cases it is not working(`string*` and `*string*`). Please help me to solve this.

Example strings

```
console.log(parser.parse("*string"));
console.log(parser.parse("*string*"));
console.log(parser.parse("string*"));
console.log(parser.parse("string"));
```

Expected output

```
{star: "start", text: "string"}
{star: "wrapped", text: "string"}
{star: "end", text: "string"}
{star: "no_star", text: "string"}
```

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-testing-sandbox-forked-5nrj4?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

```js
TEXT = text:[^* ]+ { return text; }
```

Solved my issue.